# My JButton action listener is not working

Tags: java, swing, action, listener, jbutton

My `ActionListener` codes for a `JButton` to go to another `JPanel`, but it's not working properly, though it used to work before. My code is as follows:

```
JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JPanel contentPane = new ListofDuties2(myFrame);
      myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
      myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
      myFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
});
btnNext.setBounds(194, 381, 89, 23);
add(btnNext);
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: Check out [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a cleaner approach

Answer (score 4):

When adding/removing components from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add();
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint();
```

The question is why are you using removeAll()? Any time I see code like that it means you should probably be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and then just swap panels.

Answer (score 1):

```
btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel contentPane = new ListofDuties2(myFrame);
                myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                myFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                myFrame.getContentPane().revalidate();
                myFrame.setVisible(true);
            }} );
```

You forgot a `);` in the end

Also call [`revalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29)

Comment: Doesn't removeAll automatically invalidate? and the user needs to revalidate?

Comment: @BlackBox Oh yes! It does! My bad!